# Add linearLayout below listView doesn't work

Tags: android, listview

This is not working on my phone but I can see it in the Android Studio Design mode window. I need to place a LinearLayout or any view actually just below the listView. But I can't see it, only the listView fitting the whole height

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/local_detalle_relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="android.buendia.cl.pritz.fragments.locales.LocalDetalleFragment">

    <view
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        class="com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="?android:attr/textSelectHandleLeft" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_category"
        style="@style/current_category"
        android:layout_below="@+id/banner"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/current_category">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_local_detalle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cart_bar"
            style="@style/cart_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cart_status"
                style="@style/cart_bar_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cart_next"
                style="@style/cart_bar_next"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/cart_bar_next_button_text" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove weight from listview and set fixed height

Answer (score 3):

Set `android:layout_below="@+id/list_view_local_detalle"` for `LinearLayout`

**Note** : If you'r using weight for vertical linear layout then `height` must be `0 dp` and if using for horizontal linear layout then `width` must be `0dp`.

Comment: This is right - u are in a ``RelativeLayout`` so views will overlap. Use ``below``  on the linearlayout or ``above`` on the listview, whatever you prefer more. Oh, yes, and remove the weighting entirely inside the relative, you don't need it.

Comment: When the listView is filled with the adapter data the ListView just pushed the bar below making it invisible or outside the visible area

Comment: Have you removed weight property? You don't need to assign weight property because you'r not using linearlayout as a parent anywhere.

Comment: Then you should put your second relative layout inside the scrollView.